# zsh loses precision when miltiplying two floats of significantly different magnitude

Tags: zsh, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to do some floating-point math in a zsh script. I'm seeing the following behavior:

```
$ (( a = 1.23456789 * 0.00000001 )); printf "a = %g\n" $a
a = 1.23e-08

$ (( a = 1.23456789 * 0.00000001 )); printf "a = %e\n" $a
a = 1.230000e-08

$ (( a = 1.23456789 * 0.0000001 )); printf "a = %e\n" $a
a = 1.235000e-07
```

I expect not to loose the 1st number's mantissa precision when I merely multiply it by a number whose mantissa is 1 (or at least very close to 1, if the true binary representation is considered). In other words, I'd expect to get `a = 1.23456789e-08` or maybe some truncated mantissa, but not zeros after `1.23` / `1.235`.

I'm running the following version:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)
```

Am I missing something? Or is it an issue in zsh? I'm new to zsh, and I don't have a lot of experience in shell programming in general, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Doing floating-point arithmetic in a command-line shell is a crime against nature.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And the reason for that is..? No sarcasm – as I said, shell programming is not my field of expertise, so I'd really be glad to understand. I'm just making some helper script for myself – no enterprise-level high-load production code, hehe…

Comment: It’s a kludge. Command-line shells were originally made for executing commands, and scripting features were added to them for controlling multiple commands, managing arguments to the commands and so on. Shell scripting “languages” often have poorly specified and muddled semantics, and adding floating-point features pushes them into kludge territory. Is a variable truly an IEEE-754 binary64 object, or is it a string of digits that is sometimes reinterpreted as a floating-point number? Are binary-decimal and decimal-binary conversions done properly? And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `(( x = 1.0 ))`, when x is not defined, will cause Zsh to declare the variable as `-F`: a double precision floating point which is formatted to fixed-point with 10 decimal digits on output:

```
% unset x; (( x = 0.12345678901234567 )); declare -p x
typeset -F x=0.1234567890

% unset x; x=$((0.12345678901234567)); declare -p x
typeset x=0.12345678901234566
```

I don't know why it works this way, but if you manually declare your variable as a string first, this won't happen, and you'll get the full value:

```
% unset a; typeset a; (( a = 1.23456789 * 0.00000001 )); printf "a = %g\n" $a
a = 1.23457e-08
```

Comment: Yup, I get full precision: `$ unset a; typeset a; (( a = 1.23456789 * 0.00000001 )); printf "a = %.17e\n" $a` ⇒ `a = 1.23456788999999987e-08`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes from the way of how you pass the value of `a` to `printf`. If you write it as

```
(( a = 1.23456789 * 0.00000001 )); printf "a = %e\n" $((a))
```

$ (( a = 1.23456789 * 0.0000001 )); printf "a = %e\n" $((a))

the problem does not occur. This is described [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html), where it says:

> floating point numbers can be declared with the float builtin; there are two types, differing only in their output format, as described for the typeset builtin. The output format can be bypassed by using arithmetic substitution instead of the parameter substitution, i.e. ‘${float}’ uses the defined format, but ‘$((float))’ uses a generic floating point format